# Text Mesh Pro - Auto Size plus Content Size Fitter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface

So I have a button with text in it. I am updating the text via script. Some of the buttons have more text than others so I set it up with Auto size. But even then sometimes the text doesn't fit the button so I want the button to grow to fit the text.

The issue is that with a Vertical Layout Group and Content Size fitter. The TMP_Text grows and so does the button but it grows at the max font size (even with auto-size on) Ideally I want it to only grow once it has shrunk to the smallest possible size.

I have tried so many different possibilities with Vertical Layout group and layout elements and content size fitters but I am completely at a loss as to how to get it to do what I want.

[image]
This is what I want (this is in the editor not run time and it works)

[image]
This is also in the editor

[image]
This is what I get

I noticed also that this happens with spaces. If I have one word with no spaces in between it seems to scale properly.

Edit: So I guess how would I go about getting auto-size to work with space?